# Text of US Presidents' inaugural addresses

Tags: government, text

I'm trying to reproduce some text analyses of Presidential inaugural addresses, such as was done by this [New York Times interactive display](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2009/01/17/washington/20090117_ADDRESSES.html), and I'm looking for a good source for the texts.

I've found sites ([Miller Center](http://millercenter.org/president/speeches)) that have texts of speeches in human-accessible formats (via browsing web pages), but I'm hoping there's some machine-friendly archive that I haven't found.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not formatted much better than what you've already found (I haven't checked the HTML), but UC-Santa Barbara's American Presidency Project has them as well: http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/inaugurals.php